# Проблема с отображением на Android 4.4

Tags: html, вёрстка

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема. При отображении сайта на мобильных устройствах неверно отображается слайдер вверху страницы (на главной) и футер сайта. Они образаются по ширине. Пока заметил такое поведение именно на устройствах с android 4.4.

[Адрес сайта](http://okna-pronto.ru/)

**UPD**

Скрин с проблемой:

[image]

Comment: @Batyabest, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Куда уж размернутее - открываете сайт на мобильном устройстве (телефон, планшет и т.д.) м android 4.4.2, например. И увидите, что слайдер на главной обрезан по ширине. Он отображается не полностью

Comment: Никто не подскажет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас для класса article стоит ширина 960px, а у остального контента она автоматическая. Нужно добавить для класса .header .widget-slider, .widget-call ширину 688px.

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Comment: Не совсем верно, но идея верная. Был конфликт с шириной блоков. Часть из них имели 100% ширину, а часть 960px; margin:0 auto. Не совсем те правки внес, что Вы сказали.
Обернул footer блоком <div style="height: 240px; background-color: #E4E4E4;">. По слайдеру внес правки такие: <section class="strip" style="width: 960px;margin: 0 auto;">

Comment: Рад, что смог хоть как-то помочь :-)